# Gradle cannot find JDK

Tags: java, gradle

I've created a gradle project with the following configuration:

```
group '...'
version '0.0'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useTestNG()

    beforeTest { descriptor ->
        logger.lifecycle("Running test: " + descriptor)
    }
}
```

When I execute "gradle build" I have the following error message:

> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK
>   (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to
>   point to the according directory.

This is weird since I have $JAVA_HOME set:

```
✗ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
✗ $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
```

Comment: Are you using any IDE?

Comment: Yes, but I am building it from a terminal

Comment: If this may help, I am using IDEA

Comment: Check if you have the JDK correctly configured in your IDE.

Comment: How JDK setup in IDE can interfere with a console tool?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I've found a solution.

To fix this issue I simply executed:

```
./gradlew build
```

This did the trick.