# JDK installation not found by flutter starter app

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle

I have cloned [the flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter) and installed the [Android SDK command-line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio), setting them up in `$HOME/Android`. I then made `flutter` aware of the `SDK` installation by setting `$ANDROID_HOME` to `$HOME/Android`. Things seem to have worked out, with `<path-to-flutter> doctor` finding

- `Android SDK`
- my Java JDK 8 installation (`openjdk-8-jdk` package on `Ubuntu 18.04`), and
- a connected Android phone with USB debugging

I am now trying to follow the [test-run instructions](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive?tab=terminal) for building a first app on the command line. `<path-to-flutter> create myapp` works and produces a `myapp` directory. I then try to run the resulting starter app:

```
cd myapp
~/myapp$ ANDROID_HOME=~/Android JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 <path-to-flutter> run
```

This results in the following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on ONEPLUS A6013 in debug mode...
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.                    
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 10s                                                     
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        11.0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have seen this issue [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289233/gradle-cannot-find-jdk) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286542/kotlin-could-not-find-the-required-jdk-tools-in-the-java-installation), but none of those replies seem to address it (in my case, at least). You can see from the command that I am exporting the right `$JAVA_HOME`, and besides, running

```
./android/gradlew build
```

inside the `myapp` directory does work:

```
~/myapp$ ./android/gradlew build

> Task :buildEnvironment

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

classpath
No dependencies

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 319ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

So this seems to be specific to `flutter` itself somehow, rather than `gradle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this must have been a path issue. The Flutter starter app builds (and pops up on my device) after inserting the following snippet in a file sourced in my profile (my `.bashrc`):

```
# Java
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64

# Android
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Android
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=${HOME}/Android

# Flutter
export FLUTTER_HOME=${HOME}/repos/flutter
PATH=${FLUTTER_HOME}/bin:$PATH; export PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this -->

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove openjdk*
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

now goto to home and visible your hidden folder by pressing ctrl+h

Now open .bashrc or your .rc

paste these on last

```
export PATH="$PATH:/snap/bin/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/java"
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/<YOUR USER NAME>/Android/Sdk
```

then run

```
source ~/bashrc
flutter doctor -v
```